smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect')
I am trying to integrate SMTP Email Service of Outlook in my project and And I am getting the above mentioned Error in the title. I am trying to trigger Automated email after certain operation completed successfully.
I have followed below steps to resolve it out :

I have tried by Enabling the MFA and creating App password and by using the same, still I am getting the same error.
I have reset the settings in the email which I am using for SMTP service, but still getting error of Authentication unsuccessfully.
I have tried to use SMTP Authentication Configuration by Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is disabled as well but still getting the same error

